# WPF Catch event if SmartCard is inserted

Tags: c#, wpf, smartcard, catel

If I insert a Card in my SmartCard reader on my device. I want to trigger an event in my WPF project. Any idea's to achieve that?

Comment: This doesn't really have anything to do with WPF. See this question and its answer: [Smart Card Reader Plugin (Card Inserted) Event](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40786160/smart-card-reader-plugin-card-inserted-event)

Comment: This solution cannot be implemented in WPF...

Comment: Why is that? What prevents you from creating the class in WPF?

Comment: My mistake, it seems UWP only, which I find hard to believe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question was a while ago but I can confirm it is possible.  You can reference UWP assemblies. [Calling Windows 10 APIs From a Desktop Application](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2017/01/25/calling-windows-10-apis-desktop-application/#wh8lmsBkopjqvpSP.97) details how to add the references.

> Right click on References. Select “Add Reference…” from the context
>   menu. On the left of the Reference Manager, choose Browse and find the
>   following file: C:Program Files (x86)Windows Kits10UnionMetadatawinmd.
>   Add it to your project as a reference. Note: You will need to change
>   the filter to “All Files”.
>
> Right click on References. Select “Add Reference…” from the context menu. On the left of the Reference Manager, go to Browse and
>   find the directory “C:Program Files (x86)Reference
>   AssembliesMicrosoftFramework.NETCorev4.5”. Add
>   System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.dll to your project.

From there I follow this example [Getting all Cards](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/SmartCard/cs/Scenario7_ListAllCards.xaml.cs) simply cutting and pasting the major part. Once you have reader you can then add the [Card Added Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.smartcards.smartcardreader.cardadded)

```
string selector = SmartCardReader.GetDeviceSelector();
DeviceInformationCollection devices = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(selector);

foreach (DeviceInformation device in devices)
{
    SmartCardReader reader = await SmartCardReader.FromIdAsync(device.Id);

    // For each reader, we want to find all the cards associated
    // with it.  Then we will create a SmartCardListItem for
    // each (reader, card) pair.
    IReadOnlyList<SmartCard> cards = await reader.FindAllCardsAsync();

    foreach (SmartCard card in cards)
    {
        SmartCardProvisioning provisioning = await SmartCardProvisioning.FromSmartCardAsync(card);

        SmartCardListItem item = new SmartCardListItem()
        {
            ReaderName = card.Reader.Name,
            CardName = await provisioning.GetNameAsync()
        };

        cardItems.Add(item);
    }
}
```